# Google App Script randomly stop executing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that basically take info from a website for multiple users, and put these info in a google spreadsheet, with one sheet per users.

I have a function that remove values of the firstline, resize every columns, and put back the setValues:

```js
function adjustColumnsAndIgnoreFirstLine(sheet) {
  Logger.log('--- Adjust columns ---')
  const range = sheet.getRange("1:1")

  // save the title line
  const datas = range.getValues();
  // clear it
  range.clearContent();

  // format without the title lines
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()
  sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, lastColumn);

  // set width to a minimum
  for (var i = 1; i < 37; i++) { // fixed number of columns
    if (sheet.getColumnWidth(i) < 30) {
      sheet.setColumnWidth(i, 30);
    }
  }

  // put back titles
  range.setValues(datas);
}
```

my problem is that the script stop executing in the middle of the function. I still have the "execution please wait" popup, but in the logs, the script stopped like there was no error (execution finished) with this as the last log: [image: last log]

And, on the google spreadsheet:

[image: spreadsheet]

One thing to note is that the problem doesn't comes from the script itself, as I do not encounter this problem on any of my machines, but my client does. My client ran the script on different navigator (chrome and edge), and had the same problem, but on different users (sometimes it blocks at the before-last user, sometimes at the before-before-last user...)

So I'm kinda lost on this problem...

Comment: Can you provide a copy of a spreadsheet where this behavior can be reproduced? It's hard to know what's going on based on the information provided.

Comment: Try using lock service

Comment: the spreadsheet is composed of sensible data, so i cannot share it. but i will provide as much information as required.

lock service ?

Comment: In this case, consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not clear how this script should stop at a certain column. Would it be possible to provide a spreadsheet with all sensible data removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually a timeout. Google app script limit the execution time of a script at ~6 minutes.

There is existing issues for this